# Building soloud example with emscripten not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gnu-make, emscripten

I am trying to port a project of mine to the web with emscripten, and one of the libraries I use in it is soloud. Building the library itself compiles fine with no errors, but when I try to compile one of the examples with it, I get a bunch of compiler errors.

Here are the steps I use to build the library:

1. Download and build [genie](https://github.com/bkaradzic/GENie)
2. Download [soloud](https://github.com/jarikomppa/soloud) and put `genie` executable in build folder
3. Run `./genie --with-miniaudio-only gmake`
4. `cd` into `gmake` directory and run `emmake make`

This compiles fine with no errors, however when I try to build the `simplest` example with `emcc main.cpp libsoloud_static.a -I ../include -o index.html`, I get these errors

```
emcc: warning: libsoloud_static.a: archive is missing an index; Use emar when creating libraries to ensure an index is created [-Wemcc]
emcc: warning: libsoloud_static.a: adding index [-Wemcc]
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6Soloud19getActiveVoiceCountEv (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: Link with `-sLLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-sERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6Soloud19getActiveVoiceCountEv may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6Soloud4initEjjjjj (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6Soloud4initEjjjjj may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6Soloud4playERNS_11AudioSourceEffbj (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6Soloud4playERNS_11AudioSourceEffbj may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6Soloud6deinitEv (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6Soloud6deinitEv may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6SoloudC1Ev (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6SoloudC1Ev may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6SoloudD1Ev (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6SoloudD1Ev may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6Speech7setTextEPKc (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6Speech7setTextEPKc may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6SpeechC1Ev (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6SpeechC1Ev may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6SpeechD1Ev (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6SpeechD1Ev may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
error: undefined symbol: _ZN6SoLoud6Thread5sleepEi (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: __ZN6SoLoud6Thread5sleepEi may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I was able to get it to work by changing this

```
CC  = gcc
CXX = g++
AR  = ar
```

to this

```
CC  = emcc
CXX = em++
AR  = emar
```

and this

```
  ALL_CPPFLAGS       += $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MP $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
  ALL_ASMFLAGS       += $(ASMFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -msse4.1 -fPIC
  ALL_CFLAGS         += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -msse4.1 -fPIC
  ALL_CXXFLAGS       += $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -msse4.1 -fPIC
  ALL_OBJCFLAGS      += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -msse4.1 -fPIC
  ALL_OBJCPPFLAGS    += $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -msse4.1 -fPIC
```

to this

```
  ALL_CPPFLAGS       += $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MP $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
  ALL_ASMFLAGS       += $(ASMFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fPIC
  ALL_CFLAGS         += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fPIC
  ALL_CXXFLAGS       += $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fPIC
  ALL_OBJCFLAGS      += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fPIC
  ALL_OBJCPPFLAGS    += $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ARCH) -g -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fPIC
```

(still not sure why I had to remove the `-msse4.1` flag, but I was getting a weird error)

in `SoloudStatic.make`. For some reason it was still using a regular compiler instead of emscripten.